# Java Spring + ReactJs

Tags: java, spring, jsp, reactjs

There is this typical traditional JAVA Spring + JSP application that I am working on. It's a full fledged working application with more than 50 pages. The client feels its slower and wants to make it faster by using ReactJs for new pages. From performance point I understand his concerns. Now I am not a JAVA expert and I am new to ReactJS but i have worked on AngularJs(SPA) applications extensively before.

Right now the way the application works is when we call a url say http://example.com/mycontroller/myaction.do, the app maps the url to certain controller and action in a JAVA controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mycontroller/myaction.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView myfunction(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("myJSPPage");
    mav.addObject("pageDetails", myPageDetails);
    return mav;
}
```

Once the action gets executed the html page is rendered in the browser along with server data and jQuery takes care of the UI part.

Now speaking of ReactJs,

```
React is just a UI, Lots of people use React as the V in MVC.
```

Which comes to my questions:

1. Can i use React in Java JSP Pages and access Java variables in React ?
2. If not what are other options/ways to use React with these kind of applications.
3. If its not possible to use React in current application, do i need to write the whole application from scratch using React. What are the challenges i might face?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its possible to pass the Java objects and lists to your javascript application using [Nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) which comes bundled with java 8.

Second option is to do the rendering on client and fetch the required data using ajax/websockets.

Answer (score 0):

I believe sticking to using JSP’s along with React won’t benefit you much in terms of performance. Because the main benefit of using SPA’s is that you don’t need to re-render the whole web page when some data changes or when actions are dispatched.
If performance is your main concern then I encourage you to implement a React application (the V) and make Spring your controller (the C) and make them communicate JSON objects (the M (data)).